# rsync exclude a folder containing a .git sub dir (--filter)

Tags: linux, backup, rsync

I want to backup multiple folders. In this multiple folders I want to exclude all directories, which contain a `.git` subdirectory. So for example in this folder hierarchy:

```
├── gitrepo        <-- exclude this completely
|   └── .git/...
│   └── file1
└── nogitrepo      <-- keep this
    └── file2
```

I already successfully excluded all .git directories with `--exclude=.git`, but since all the contents of the local repositories happen to be already in the remote SCM, I don't want to include them in my backup.

I'm aware of the `--filter` argument of rsync. I looked into the man page but I'm not sure it will solve this problem. But I'm optimistic since rsync beforehand assembles a file list of all including files.

So, is it possible with rsync to exclude all folders that are git repositories? Something like the per-directory rule for `--filter`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setup your `SRC` and `DEST` variables, for example:

```
SRC="./"
DEST="../BACKUP/"
```

You can use something like `find` to locate all `.git` directories:

```
find "${SRC}" -type d -name '.git'
```

This will include `${SRC}/.git` too though (which will become `${SRC}`, and thus ultimately ignore "*everything*")... to avoid that use `-mindepth 2`:

```
find "${SRC}" -mindepth 2 -type d -name '.git'
```

Next strip off the trailing `/.git` components:

```
find "${SRC}" -mindepth 2 -type d -name '.git' \
    | sed -re 's!/.git$!!g'
```

As `rsync` will set its working directory to the source, we need to trim the initial `${SRC}` from the results too:

```
find "${SRC}" -mindepth 2 -type d -name '.git' \
    | sed -re 's!^'"${SRC}"'!!g;s!/.git$!!g'
```

Finally, join this with the `rsync` command, using `--exclude-from`, passing `-` (i.e: `stdin`):

```
find "${SRC}" -mindepth 2 -type d -name '.git' \
    | sed -re 's!^'"${SRC}"'!!g;s!/.git$!!g' \
    | rsync -av --exclude-from - "${SRC}" "${DEST}"/
```

---

**NOTE:** this won't pick up *any* untracked / modified files.

Comment: This solved it thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`find your_DIR_for_BACKUP -name .git | sed 's/\/.git//g' > ~/exclude_repos`

and run rsync with --exclude-from option, pick filled file ~/exclude_repos

`rsync --exclude-from ~/exclude_repos your_DIR_for_BACKUP_SRC DST`

Comment: most minimalistic answer, but solved it too! for the sake of completeness maybe only add the `-d` directory flag to `find`